# Add two calculated columns to view with "WHERE" clauses

Tags: mysql

I'm using this to create a view with all the columns from a table plus one new column with a value based on a calculation from two other columns. I have this working fine to add one column:

```
CREATE VIEW `calculated_full` AS
SELECT *, 
`planned`-`actual_widget` AS `widget_delta` FROM `joined_table` where product = "widgets"
```

Basically, this is saying perform this calculation between these two columns, but only if a third (`product`) has a certain value. This works fine.

However, I need to do this to add another calculated column to the view that should be performed only if the third column (`product`) has a different value. Like this (which of course doesn't work).

```
CREATE VIEW `calculated_full` AS
SELECT *, 
`planned`-`actual_widget` AS `widget_delta` FROM `joined_table` where product = "widgets", 
`planned`-`actual_knob` AS `knobs_delta` FROM `joined_table` where product = "knobs"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you want the calculation to be performed by row, and that all values are in the same table, if so, you can perform the calculation selectively using the equivalent of an if statement, the `CASE` statement.

When a case is not found this will return null.

```
select *,
case when product = "widgets" then `planned`-`actual_widget` end  as widget_delta,
case when product = "knobs" then `planned`-`actual_knobs` end as knobs_delta
from joined-table
```

If you do not want it to return null, just add the `ELSE` clause:

```
case when condition then value_if_true else value_if_false end
```

The `CASE` statement may also be written like this:

```
case product when "widget" then widgetvalue end
```

or if you need multiple cases:

```
case product
     when "widget" then widgetvalue
     when "knob" then knobvalue
     else defaultvalue
end
```

Comment: Actually, your way might work too, but it would need an "IF" because the calculation is different based on what the `product` column value is.

Comment: see answer, above, the CASE statement should help  you